# Importing modules in JS

Tags: javascript, npm, import, lodash

I got a problem that I struggle with for a long time and it's about importing modules to my main JS script.

I downloaded a lodash library via npm and I want to import it into my main script in order to use its functionalities. Here's the code:

```
import * as _ from './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js';

console.log(_.head([1,2,3]))
```

However, when I'm running the script I receive such an error:

> ```
> !  ▶ Uncaught TypeError: _.head is not a function
>         <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/playground.js:43
>       [Więcej informacji]
> >> _.head([1,2])
> <- 1
> ```

As you can see, I cannot use `_.head` in the script, but I can use it from the console, which - I think - means that lodash was imported correctly.

What might be the cause of this problem? Also, I don't know if it's just me or is importing modules really such a painful thing to do? Maybe you can recommend some articles on this topic?
Thank you for all the replies in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need or probably want that path. If you've installed lodash via `npm`, `yarn`, or another package manager, use:

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

or possibly

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

depending on how lodash handles its exports.

Comment: I've already tried it and I'm always receiving ,,TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: "lodash". Relative modules specifiers must start with „./”, „../” or „/”'.

Comment: @Wiktor - It sounds like you're trying to use a package manager for client-side development without using a bundler. This is, unfortunately, one of the areas where it's become very confusing lately. If you just want to use lodash in a browser without a bundler, follow "Installation / In a browser" [here](https://lodash.com/). You can grab a local copy and serve it, or use a CDN like https://unpkg.com/ or https://cdnjs.com/. For instance, `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>` will give you v4.17.21. No `import` needed, just use `_`.

Comment: (I couldn't find an example of using `import` syntax with lodash outside of Node.js or a bundler.)

Comment: Oh, so that's what the whole issue was about! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's my pleasure. :-) This is an area that's **very** confusing right now. It's not you. :-)